# What inputs go into encrypting / creating an ASP.NET Forms Authentication Ticket?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, forms-authentication, formsauthentication, formsauthenticationticket

Everything I read points to the MachineKey element in the web.config file being the only thing that determines the encrypted ticket value, but I have a lot of evidence to contradict that at the moment.

So my question is: **what can make the ticket encryption value (particularly the length) different, given that the machine key and the data inside the ticket is identical?**

**EDIT**

We are seeing the changes in the value as a result of timestamps.  However in one of the environments the created values themselves are much shorter.  Two of the sites (.NET 4, MVC2/3) cope with it just fine.  A .NET 2.0 / WebForms site, however, can't decrypt it with the same machine key.

Comment: Wow...voted down for a legitimate question about how Forms Authentication tickets are created.  Thanks unnamed voter!

Comment: Would be better if you explained you "lot of evidence" but I +1'd the counteract

Comment: I wish my downvoter had communicated that...hopefully my update helps

Comment: Have you fixed the `machineKey` values in your `machine.config`?

Comment: We've got them in the web.config in each of our applications.  Can the machine.config override that?

Comment: All all your apps in the same pool? Do they all use the same key or different keys?

Comment: Same key but different pools.  One for each app.

Comment: Are you saying that the .NET 2.0 can't decrypt the ticket provided from another of the apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while the MachineKey and encryption algorithm do decide the encrypted value produced, we have confirmed that there are [definitely patches that can affect machine key encryption / decription.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/30/asp-net-security-fix-now-on-windows-update.aspx)

This became evident when half of our web farm was patched, which produced encrypted tickets of different lengths than the others.  It was a large set of patches, so we were unable to determine the exact patch that caused the different behavior.

So...if anyone else experiences this very strange behavior, **make sure you compare the patches and hotfixes applied to each server when troubleshooting.**

Answer (score 1):

MachineKey determines how it is encrypted/decrypted.  The contents include a timestamp so even if you put in the same data, that would explain the different encrypted values.

Comment: Yeah that change isn't causing us any trouble...please see my update above.